# How can I add namespace to revealing prototype pattern

Tags: javascript

I have this code,

```
var MyNamespace = MyNamespace || {};

MyNamespace.Calculator = function (eq) {
        //state goes here
        this.eqCtl = document.getElementById(eq);
    };

MyNamespace.Calculator.prototype = function () {
        //private members
        var add = function (x, y) {
            this.eqCtl.innerHTML = x + y;
        },
        subtract = function (x, y) {
            this.eqCtl.innerHTML = x - y;
        };

        //public members
        return {
            add: add,
            subtract: subtract
        };
    } ();

Var calc = new MyNamespace.Calculator('eqCtl');
calc.add(2,2);
```

**Questions**

Why am I getting exception after adding "MyNamespace" to it ? It works if I remove it...

It's recommended not to use "new" keyword for creating objects by Douglas Crockford Then how can I overcome this solution.

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bpo50qjg/

Comment: *"Yahoo's duglas"* is properly called Douglas Crockford. Yes, Crockford has an issue with `new`. No, that doesn't mean you shouldn't use it. It means *Crockford thinks* you shouldn't use it. Important distinction. Read his arguments against, consider the arguments for, and make your own decision.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder thanks, and you are right but I will need time to even understand why Douglas is saying that, I will do my research sometime in future

Comment: why negative vote ? is it because of the pattern or my mistake ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a typo in:

```
Var calc = new MyNamespace.Calculator('eqCtl');
```

It should be:

```
var calc = ...
```

Comment: i think you forgot to click on update @Fiddle :), as you are passing link to my original fiddle